# Swift 3 - To the power of (pow) function not working as expected

Tags: swift, pow

Please could somebody help me.  I am trying to run a simple compounding calculation in Swift.

Formula I am trying to recreate:
T = P(1+r/n)^(n*t), where
T = Total, P = Starting amount, r = interest rate, n = number of times compounded and t = number of years

My code as follows:

```
    import Darwin
    var total: Double
    var startingAmount: Double = 5000.00
    var interestRate: Double = 0.05
    var numberOfTimesCompounded: Double = 4.0
    var numberOfYears: Double = 2.0
    var totalYear1: Double
    var toThePowerOf: Double

    totalYear1 = startingAmount * (1 + interestRate / numberOfTimesCompounded)
    toThePowerOf = numberOfTimesCompounded * number of years
    total = pow(totalYear1,toThePowerOf)
```

The answer to the formula should be 5,522.43

In my code above, TotalYear1 = 5062.50 (which is correct) and toThePowerOf = 8.0 (which is correct)  However, total shows = 4314398832739892000000.00 which clearly isn't right.  Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with my calculation of total?

Many thanks

Comment: `5062` to the power of `8` is `431099110317531071833153904896`, the `pow()` function *does* work as expected.

Comment: Seems that Swift code is correct, while the formula isn't.

Comment: Doh!...me being stupid.  Makes sense now.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've actually implemented `T = (P(1+r/n))^(n*t)`, which doesn't even make dimensional sense.

`startingAmount` needs to be multiplied at the end, it **can't** be part of the `pow`:

```
totalYear1 = (1 + interestRate / numberOfTimesCompounded)
toThePowerOf = numberOfTimesCompounded * number of years // [sic]
total = startingAmount * pow(totalYear1,toThePowerOf)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for your time